# Window saver for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, window-manager

Does anybody know of any software for Mac OS X which will save your program windows, so when you boot up again you can return to the same windows?  This would be a huge help since as a developer I often have 10 windows open and often have to re-open and re-size them all when I reboot.

Comment: It's called "Lion"…?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of Mac OS X, [Lion](http://www.apple.com/macosx/) (10.7) has this feature bult-in. It's called [Resume](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#resume).

From Apple:

> Now apps you close will reopen right where you left off, so you never have to start from scratch again. And when you install software updates, you no longer need to save your work, close your apps, and spend valuable time setting everything up again. With Resume, you can restart your Mac and return to what you were doing — with all your apps in the places where you left them.

This happens automatically. Not all apps support it yet, but those that don't should be updated soon for full support.

Mac OS X Lion costs $29, and is [available on the Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-lion/id444303913?mt=12).

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Im definitely trying it this weekend!